# how can i create custom grid column with radio button in custom module in magento

Tags: magento, grid, radio-button

i want to create custom grid column with radio button in it. i have created with following code,but the problem is,i am not getting radio button name thats why  radio button can be selected to multiple.....help me to get radio button name.

```
protected function _prepareColumns()<br/>
    { 
$this->addColumn('pr_id',<br/>
            array( <br/>
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('p_id'),<br/>
                'index' => 'entity_id',<br/>
         'type' => 'radio',<br/>
         'name' => 'prid',<br/>
         'width' => '50px',<br/>

    ));
```

........

please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->addColumn('pr_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('p_id'),
        'type'      => 'radio',
        'html_name' => 'prid[]',
        'align'     => 'center',
        'value'    => array('1')
    ));
```

Comment: http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/07/12/magento-add-radiocheckbox-button-in-custom-column-in-admin-grid/